# How can I do this with bat for looping

Tags: file, loops, batch-file, for-loop

I want to loop these to output sth.

```
@echo off
set ans=yyynny
echo %ans:~0,1%
echo %ans:~1,1%
echo %ans:~2,1%
echo %ans:~3,1%
echo %ans:~4,1%
echo %ans:~5,1%
pause
```

Output:

```
y
y
y
n
n
y
```

After "help for" i got

```
set ans=yyynny
for /l %%i in (0,1,5) do (echo %ans:~%%i,1%)
pause
```

of courses, it doesnt work. It outputs these:

```
yyynny
yyynny
yyynny
yyynny
yyynny
```

How can i tackle the problem? Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative not using delayed expansion:

```
set ans=yyynny
for /l %%i in (0,1,5) do (call echo %%ans:~%%i,1%%)
```

Comment: how can u know that "call" should be placed at the begining

Comment: @KenTakLee I'm sorry but I do not understand your question.

Comment: ....    i am asking that why do u know u should for /l %%i in (0,1,5) do (call echo %%ans:~%%i,1%%) instead of for /l %%i in (0,1,5) do (echo %%ans:~%%i,1%%)

Comment: @KenTakLee it's just a method used to evaluate variables in sequence (stages), instead of all at once

Comment: @KenTakLee Not sure where I saw call trick first, but [this site](http://ss64.com/nt) has loads of useful info, similar technique included

Answer (score 1):

The expansion of variables inside `FOR` loops requires you to **enable delayed expansion** to force variables to be expanded at runtime instead of being expanded when parsed.

Try

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set ans=yyynny
for /l %%i in (0,1,5) do (echo !ans:~%%i,1!)
```

Note that the variable is referenced with an slightly different syntax `!ans!` instead of  `%ans%`.

Comment: While delayed expansion helps, it just because it allows usage of other variable notation so expression is unambiguous.  Expand time is not a factor here. `%ans:~%%i,1%` is actually parsed differently that we assume, it's split into two expressions:  `%ans:~%` being first and `%i,1%` being second. First is actual string, second empty hence the result.

Comment: you are right @wmz. The solution would be to split into two assignments, using a temporary variable. But, then that would require delayed expansion.

Comment: Did u just try switching ! and %

Comment: NOTE: The expansion of variables inside `FOR` loops _does not_ **require** you to use delayed expansion. As [wmz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1123692) mentioned [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11740010/1126551) you **can also** use `call`